# How can i call a parameter's function to a $http get method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm new over here in stackoverflow.

Well I have a problem with my code and i couldn't find a solution, so I decide to ask my question here.

HTML

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    </div>

<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
```

> I included ng-app="app" in my body and I installed angularjs as well.

I added a javascript file in my application called ang.js

ang.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.controller("ctrl", function ($http) {
    $http.get("url1")
    .success(function (response){
        console.log(response);
    })
    $http.get("url2", {
        params: {
            Id: response[0].key
        }
    .success(function (response2) {
        console.log(response2);
       })
    })
    })
```

My question is in

```
.success(function (response){
        console.log(response);
    })
```

How can i call this parameter response in the second one.

```
$http.get("url2", {
        params: {
            Id: response
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the second request in the success handler of the first, ie

```
var promise = $http.get('url1').then(function(res1) {
    return $http.get('url2', {
        params: {
            Id: res1.data[0].key
        }
    }).then(function(res2) {
        console.log(res2.data);
        return res2.data;
    })
});
```

Note that I've used `then` instead of the [deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice) `success` callback.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.